# Displaying two cells per row in CollectionView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to set my collection view cell sizes so that I get two cells per row.

I have looked at plenty of solution for sizing cells for collection views. I actually have used some solutions before for sizing three cells per row that have worked for me.

What I have so far:

```
extension BusinessViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (view.frame.width - 20) / 2.0
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

}
```

Right now I just get one big cell per row and I don't know why. Usually when I have to have 3 cells per row, simply subtracting the insets from the views width and dividing by the number of desired cells is enough. Not sure why this is causing me an issue.

Comment: This is working. I would suggest to check `view.frame.width`. If possible use `collectionView.bounds.width` . This maybe issue due to your collectionView not fitting cells properly

Comment: I've just tried your code. And it works fine. Share all your code connected with collectionView.

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking the "estimatesSize" property of UICollectionView.
It could have been set to "Automatic" instead of "None".
I solved the same problem with this solution